# sccs mixins folder is not accepted by preprocessor

Tags: sass

I've set up my own (Bootstrap 3) scss mixins as it is done in Bootstrap itself:
a mixin folder in my scss folder (template). Like this:

```
-scss (with template.scss)
-- bootstrap
-- template/mixins
```

linked it in the file template.scss: @import "template/mixins";

Prepros doesn't accept it: "File to import not found or unreadable: template/mixins".

How do I set this up?

Answer (score 0):

Found it. The folder was set up correctly, but the corresponding @import was not. One level too high. @import mixins shouldn't be in template.scss, but in the template folder itself as _mixins.scss